# How to calculate torque of the motor?

Tags: motor, dc-motor

I have bought a motor from amazon. But the problem is no data is provided with it.

Now I want to calculate the torque of the motor. I have measured the current and voltage of the motor.
At 8.57V it consumes 0.05Amps of current. Now I want to calculate its torque.
Size of motor- 1cm dia and 3 cm length 200gms and cylindrical in shape.

The method I used is taking Electrical power= Mechanical power
So the electrical power for the motor is \$ 8.57V\cdot 0.05A=0.4285 W\$

Mechanical power is \$F\cdot v= 0.4285[W]= F\cdot 10[m/s]\$

\$F= 0.04285\ N\$

Now torque \$T=F\cdot r\$

\$T=0.04285\cdot 0.01\$

\$T=0.004285\ Nm \$

So it this calculation correct or not.
Also what does T=0.04285Nm signifies in practical terms for example- it can lift 0.04285N weight for 1 meter vertically.

Also how to calculate how much weight it can carry horizintally.

Comment: Use MathJax to write equations. It's not like you imagine, there is a loss in between electrical and mechanical conversion. How did you measure the force 0.04285N ?

Comment: _"At 8.57V it consumes 0.05Amps of current"_ - this is not enough information. You bought the motor from Amazon, can you provide a link to it or a title/description? Can you measure its speed (rpm)?

Comment: _"Size of motor- 1cm dia and 3 cm length 200gms"_ - 10mm diameter x 30mm length, and weighs 200g? What is it made out of, unobtainium?

Comment: Where did the 10 m/s come from?

Comment: " have bought a motor from amazon. But the problem is no data is provided with it.". Now you know why "No Datasheet : No Sale" is a useful rule.

Comment: 10 m/s is an assumption where I assumed how much force is required to drive a particular thing at 10 m/s where power is constant.

Comment: https://www.amazon.in/Dynamo-Generator-Science-Projects-Experiments/dp/B07TXHNDNC/ref=pd_yo_rr_rp_1/262-2556012-7651250?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_i=B07TXHNDNC&pd_rd_r=c2de4608-b999-43a4-a2f0-eb35a658a3c4&pd_rd_w=dQpg5&pd_rd_wg=Prc1f&pf_rd_p=1a0112c2-5c6c-48a4-9f9c-8abc1a342708&pf_rd_r=KDS852JQ0WWBR7K9SCCW&psc=1&refRID=KDS852JQ0WWBR7K9SCCW Link to the motor bought from amazon if it can help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a 200 g motor, 400 mW power consumption sounds awfully low. It sounds like you are running the motor at no load.

If you want to measure or estimate the torque into a load by the mechanical power = electrical power method, then you need to put a load on the motor. Suitable loads include a fan, another motor/generator driving resistors for a load, or a friction or electromagnetic brake.

Assuming 100% efficiency would give you an upper bound on mechanical power output. Given the motor size, it's likely to be much less than that.

Once loaded with a suitable mechanical load, you'll need to measure or estimate the motor speed, as the output power in watts is torque (Nm) times angular speed (radians/s). Conversion between rpm or rev/s to rads/s is fairly straightforward.

Once you have measured voltage V, current I and motor speed ω when loaded, and estimated your expected efficiency η, your torque at that load and current will be

torque = ηVI/ω

If you can actually measure the torque, by mounting the load on a balance, or by winding a weight up round a drum, then a more interesting calculation is to calculate the efficiency.

Comment: I have another motor which is 4 times the size and weight of the motor I am talking about which has all the details like torque provided is 6200 gm-cm. So it is wise to assume the torque of smaller motor as 6200/4=1550 gm-cm.

Comment: @TusharDubey If the motors have roughly the same speed, and in the absence of any other information, that's a better figure to use than any baseless guess. You will certainly be within a factor of 10, you may even get within a factor of 2.